# KO.mapping + KO.validation, how to validate two properties using validation mapping

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-validation

```
 var validationMapping = {

        emailAddress: {
            create: function (options) {
                return ko.observable(options.data).extend({ required: true }).extend({email:true});
            }
        },
        emailAddressConfirm: {
            create: function (options) {
                return ko.observable(options.data).extend({ required: true }).extend({ email: true })
                .extend({equal: emailAddress});}}};
```

Above is my validation mapping that I use to when mapping a model as below

```
 $.post('getaccountdata', {},
        function (data) {
            if (data != "") {
                myViewModel = ko.validatedObservable(ko.mapping.fromJS(data, validationMapping));
                ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
            }
        });
```

The problem is this doesn't seem to work. It appears that the emailAddress object being passed to the "equal" validation function is not the observable from the view model. What is the correct syntax for specifying the "other" observable?

Comment: can you show some code of the equal function?

Answer (score 1):

Months later, but anyway ;)
The only way I found is extend the validation after the bindings :

```
...
myViewModel = ko.validatedObservable(ko.mapping.fromJS(data, validationMapping));
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
myViewModel().emailAddress.extend({ equal: myViewModel().emailAddressConfirm });
```